# Image Loop with Semantic UI slider rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm trying to loop some images attached to a post using a custom UI semantic slider from [here](https://codepen.io/hougasian/pen/RKXbLd). This is what i have tried so far but it's only showing the first image from the loop.

```
  <div class="ui text container slides">
    <i class="small left angle icon"></i>
    <i class="small right angle icon"></i>
    <div class="slide active ">
    <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
        <%= image_tag image %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here's the custom slider:

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui text container slides">
    <i class="big left angle icon"></i>
    <i class="big right angle icon"></i>
    <div class="slide active">
      <h1>Slide one</h1>
      <p>Plain text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inverted shadow blurred image slide">
      <h1>Slide two</h1>
      <p>Background image using <code>.inverted</code>, <code>.shadow</code>, and <code>.blurred</code>:</p>
      <p><code>class="inverted shadow blurred image slide"</code></p>
    </div>
    <div class="inverted salmon faded slide">
      <h1>Slide three</h1>
      <p>Background color using <code>.inverted</code>, <code>.salmon</code>, and <code>.faded</code>:</p>
      <p><code>class="inverted faded salmon slide"</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My original code without any slider:

```
<% if @job.images.attached? %>
<% (0...@job.images.count).each do |image| %>

<%= image_tag(@job.images[image]) %>

<% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= image_tag "missing.jpg" %>

                <% end %>
```

Comment: The problem isn't with your ruby code in the view but with your new class for the slider. The block of code that iterates through the @job's images is correct, so if they aren't all displaying it's an issue with your CSS / HTML class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show images in slider then you need to move the div inside the loop. 
Like this:

```
<div class="ui text container slides">
    <i class="small left angle icon"></i>
    <i class="small right angle icon"></i>
    <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
            <div class="slide">
               <%= image_tag image %> 
            </div> 
     <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to add each image inside of a different html tag. The Javascript and CSS navigate throught the different classes inside of "slide" divs.

For example:

```
<div class="slide active">
  <h1>Slide one</h1>
  <p>Plain text.</p>
  <!-- Background Image 1 -->
</div>
<div class="inverted shadow blurred image slide">
  <h1>Slide two</h1>
  <!-- Background Image 2 -->
  <p><code>class="inverted shadow blurred image slide"</code></p>
</div>
<div class="inverted salmon faded slide">
  <h1>Slide three</h1>
  <!-- Background Image 3 -->
  <p><code>class="inverted faded salmon slide"</code></p>
</div>
```

If you need to create a dynamic iteration with ruby, you'll need to wrap the divs inside of your loop, like so:

```
<% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <div class="slide">
       <%= image_tag image %> <! -- Remember that this needs to be a background image -->
    </div>
<% end %>
```